# Facebook Like button shows url for my dev site

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I'm using a 503 page as a 'coming soon' splash page. It has a FB like button on it.

I have been able to get the description and title to pull across, but the url of my site is wrong..

my normal url is like example.com, and the url displayed is my dev site - dev.example.com

I have searched all the files I can think of for dev. and can't find it anywhere..

Clicking the title link provided on facebook actually takes you to the correct url, but it's just the url displayed underneath that is visually wrong.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

check the configuration of your app in fb or:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="YOUR_URL" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

or

```
<fb:like href="YOUR_URL" send="true" width="450" show_faces="true"></fb:like>
```

Comment: All the urls i can see in the app are set to the right one.
When i first click the like button it has the popup box, and that actually displays the right url! then when it gets posted to facebook it gets changed to dev.example

Comment: <div class="fb-like" data-href="YOUR_URL" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>

or

<fb:like href="YOUR_URL" send="true" width="450" show_faces="true"></fb:like>

Comment: Yep iv got the right url in the href, still dev.example ! >:(

Answer (score 0):

Is there any server side redirection from your example.com to dev.example.com? The Like button script will resolve those and present the user with the end URL.